# Ffmpeg не конвертирует при подстановке параметров через php

Tags: конвертация, php, ffmpeg

Возникла такая проблема: Апнул, значит, я ffmpeg до 2.4 full.

1. debian 7
2. wheezy
3. php 5.6

Есть сайт, в нем функция конвертации видео. Через консоль запускаю команду - всё работает. Запускаю средствами php - получаю файлик в 48 байт и ошибку:

> Layout indicates a different number of channels than actually present

Бьюсь уже неделю. Если проставляю в php `-c copy` (копирование всех параметров кодеков), то видео конвертируется как положено. Конвертация через php работает, пока не подставляю параметры. Если запустить `ffmpeg -i source.mkv -s 720x576 -c copy 1.mp4`, тогда сработает и сконвертит. Если подставишь хоть что-нибудь еще - вывалит ошибку эту. Самое странное, что через консоль на всё пофиг. Что не вводишь - всё работает.

```
exec($converter." -i $folder" .$ffile." $atata $folder" .$tt.«_». $ffile.".mp4 1> ffmpeg/block.txt 2>&1 &");
$converter = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg";    
$atata = '-s 720x576 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 1000k -r 24 -ac 2 -b:a 128k';
```

Answer (score 1):

Строки местами не перепутаны?

```
exec($converter." -i $folder" .$ffile." $atata $folder" .$tt.«_». $ffile.".mp4 1> ffmpeg/block.txt 2>&1 &");

$converter = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg";
```

Comment: Это вообще 3 разных файла. Чую все-таки дело в криво собранных кодеках.